# Bootstrap Hypothesis Testing β1=1

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, bootstrap

For the following model *yi =β0 +β1xi +εi, εi ∼IID(0,σ2)* I want to test the hypothesis that β1=1. For that I am trying to resample the residuals obtained from estimating the model under H0. How could you use **lm** to obtain residuals for the model under H0?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please post where you're stuck? Right now, it looks like you just need to know the `resid` function, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: My question is how would you estimate the model where β1 = 1, such that y is just equal to some constant β0 + the corresponding value of x and a residual?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to optimize the intercept estimate while forcing the slope to be $1?$

Comment: Exactly. I've tried it like that: lm(I(y-1*x)~1, data = data)

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: The question about testing whether the slope is exactly $1$ is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78774.  In the present context, the other question about finding the residuals translates to an expression of the form `residuals(lm(y-x ~ 1))`.